# Pandas Dataframe: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long with .astype(int64)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here, we are running the periodic background celery tasks every 15 min for wireless stats aggregation. These tasks are running successfully most of the time. But randomly approximately once in 3-4 hours task fails with below error:

```
[2691360 rows x 14 columns]::_____________Python int too large to convert to C long
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nms_backend/apps/devices/tasks.py", line 4999, in interface_stats_aggreagator
    df = df.astype({'rxDrpAvg': 'int64',
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6226, in astype
    res_col = col.astype(dtype=cdt, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6240, in astype
    new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 448, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 352, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 526, in astype
    new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 299, in astype_array_safe
    new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 230, in astype_array
    values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 170, in astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Please find the library details use for the development below:

> Python==3.8
> numpy==1.24.2
> pandas==1.5.3

We have also check the system max size is defined as below:

> import sys
> sys.maxsize
> 9223372036854775807

Dataframe type used are mentioned below:

```
df = df.astype({'rxDrpAvg': 'int64',
                'txPktAvg': 'int64',
                'rxPktAvg': 'int64',
                'txDrpAvg': 'int64',
                'cpuMemAvg': 'str',
                'packetErrorRate': 'int64',
                'rxBytesAvg': 'int64',
                'retryCount': 'int64',
                'txBytesAvg': 'int64',
                'fcsError': 'int64',
                'rxErrAvg': 'int64',
                'txErrAvg': 'int64',
                'createdAt': 'int64'
                })
```

Printing the Dataframe look like as mentioned below:

```
[2023-06-10 23:01:03,754: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] EXCEPTION_IN_SORTING_VALUES in Data_Frame: 
         device_id                            txPktAvg  ... rxErrAvg txErrAvg
0        f9b058a1-e949-4c3f-8929-f81633a61a63       18  ...        0        0
1        f9b058a1-e949-4c3f-8929-f81633a61a63       33  ...        0        0
2        f9b058a1-e949-4c3f-8929-f81633a61a63       25  ...        0        0
3        f9b058a1-e949-4c3f-8929-f81633a61a63       13  ...        0        0
4        f9b058a1-e949-4c3f-8929-f81633a61a63       23  ...        0        0
...                                       ...      ...  ...      ...      ...
2691355  32c8be9c-e661-4e2c-9936-ce03ed65db73       12  ...        0        0
2691356  32c8be9c-e661-4e2c-9936-ce03ed65db73       20  ...        0        0
2691357  32c8be9c-e661-4e2c-9936-ce03ed65db73       50  ...        0        0
2691358  32c8be9c-e661-4e2c-9936-ce03ed65db73       13  ...        0        0
2691359  32c8be9c-e661-4e2c-9936-ce03ed65db73       31  ...        0        0
```

Can anyone suggest how should we proceed for further debugging and find the cause and fix this?

Earlier the we where using the datatype as `int32`. We have also tried by changing the datatype from `int32` to `int64`, but no benefit. Based on the defined structure the only parameter with biggest length is `createdAt` as `epoch time` and `device id` as `uuid4`. We are also trying the write all the data into csv file for analysis using filter to check the data.

Can anyone suggest the further ways for the better debugging to find the cause of the issue for its correct and permanent resolution?

Please let us know if any other information is required.

Comment: What time units are you storing `createdAt`, ns?

Comment: python `int` can be (flexibly) large, so it's possible to have values that are too lange for `int32` or `int64`

Comment: Consider upgrading to pandas 2.0+ and try the [nullable type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html): `Integer`. (Note the capital `I`).

Comment: Please post the code that generates the error and all `import` lines for a [mre]. Traceback alone is not enough.

Comment: @hpaulj, Thanks for suggestion we are checking for the best way to find the parameter having such value `26lakh row` x `15 column`.

Comment: @jared, We are using the `createdAt` value as `seconds`.

Comment: I'd verify that that is the case. There's no way you're reaching the max integer size if it's just seconds. Even ns wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @jared, Yes, I completely agree on this. I suspect is unexpected data in any one row for any parameter which is tedious to figure out of 26 lakh row data.

Comment: Well, you know that it is in the `createdAt` column. If you have an idea of what the actual epoch time is, you can search the data frame for where the expected value is exceeded.

Comment: Hi @jare, I found a way to analysis the data for all `26 lakh rows and 15 column` Most probably by tomorrow we will get the clarity on the parameter and value causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing the data for complete `26 lakhs rows and 15 column` We found the cause of the problem. There were total `2 out of 15 columns` in which randomly causing the problems. It was caused because after certain time duration device was sending an un-expected `garbage value` of `20+ digits`, though the expected maximum value was approx `5-6 digits` only. Please refer the below screenshots.

[image]

We have added the data validation in pandas data-frame to avoid such issue in future.

```
df[df['txPktAvg'].str.len().le(10) & df['rxPktAvg'].str.len().le(10)]
```

It will ensure that all the allowed data in the pandas data-frame should be `<=10` and any validated column having value `>10` then the particular `row` will be `dropped` from the data-frame.